# How to calculate score for news category prediction?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, kaggle

I have function with predict category on basis of train data. Along with I want to calculate score of predicted category i.e. why it is assigned the news into specific category such as politics, worldnews or sports etc.

I am copying the function for idea

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')

def predict_category(model, head, desc):
    model.eval()
    head = head.lower()
    desc = desc.lower()
    tokenized_head = [tok.text for tok in nlp.tokenizer(head)]
    tokenized_desc = [tok.text for tok in nlp.tokenizer(desc)]
    indexed_head = [TEXT.vocab.stoi[t] for t in tokenized_head]
    indexed_desc = [TEXT.vocab.stoi[t] for t in tokenized_desc]
    tensor_head = torch.LongTensor(indexed_head).to(device)
    tensor_desc = torch.LongTensor(indexed_desc).to(device)
    tensor_head = tensor_head.unsqueeze(1)
    tensor_desc = tensor_desc.unsqueeze(1)
    prediction = model(tensor_head, tensor_desc)
    max_pred = prediction.argmax(dim=1)
    return max_pred.item()

pred = predict_category(model, "Volkswagen Finance picks up 25 per cent stake in Kuwy Technology", "The partners will also offer finance, insurance and warranty products for Volkswagen group customers on Kuwy platform.")
print(f'Predicted category is: {pred} = {LABEL.vocab.itos[pred]}')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to Pytorch, but in scikit learn it's possible to obtain the probability that an instance belongs to every class when you are making a prediction on it... maybe you could achieve the same on Pytorch